# Files in the homefolder not appearing immediately

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I have a situation which I do not understand. In our domain environment we have homefolders for each user. Then we have a terminal server(Windows 8 R2) which is running some accounting application used by our accounts department. The accounting people(using Windows 7) have a client application which connects to the accounting application running on the terminal server. (using RDP or something)

**Problem scenario**:

The accounting people usually save a `.PDF` file in their homefolder.

They use the client application on their PC to browse the same `.PDf` file from their homefolder

But unfortunately the file does not appears in the file browser. However if they directly browse to their homefolder (via windows explorer) they can verify that the `.PDF` file exists there! But after approx. 10 minutes the file is available in the file browser too!

This problems occurs only sometimes. Is there any explanation to this behaviour? Thanks